# Monitor all clusters of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autodiscovery

I was wondering if it is possible to monitor all AWS cluster environments by default. We currently have two clusters and we monitor them by having a class that creates a DescribeEnvironmentResourcesRequest request like this:

```
for (String cluster : clusters) {
            DescribeEnvironmentResourcesRequest request = new DescribeEnvironmentResourcesRequest();
            request.setEnvironmentName(cluster);

 //Code to get all beanstalk annd EC2 instances for this cluster.
```

The problem with this is , everytime we add a new cluster, we will have to modify our list of clusters (which is stored in a properties file ), redeploy this application and only then will we be able to monitor the instances in the new cluster.

Is there a way to let AWS auto discover new clusters as and when they are added, so that it solves the issue?

Comment: use tags on the "new cluster" and use this in your "code to get all beanstalk an EC2 instances"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DescribeEnvironments to retrieve a current list of available environments. From that list you get the environment resources.

API Docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_DescribeEnvironments.html
CLI Docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/describe-environments.html